# How do I simultaneously unsubscribe from all subreddits, without clicking each 'Unsubscribe' button?

Tags: reddit

The screenshot beneath portrays the titled question.

[image]

## My Attempts

I input the following 2 scripts from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/2f13er/how_do_i_unsubscribe_from_all_subreddits/ck4yzki/) into my URL bar, but my Firefox and Chrome misinterpreted  them as Google searches which didn't solve my difficulty.

> **Warning** There is no way to undo this if you clear your browser history
>
> Click the [multireddit link](http://puu.sh/beDLI/162ec4a5a7.png) on [this page](http://www.reddit.com/subreddits/mine/). Once you click it and get redirected, paste this into the address bar and click enter:
>
> `javascript:(function(){var%20q=[];$('.remove').each(function(){var%20that=this;var%20f=function(index){$(that).trigger('click');$(that).trigger('mousedown');setTimeout(function(){if(q[index]){q[index](index+1);}else{if(downVoteTimer){window.clearTimeout(upVoteTimer);}}},500);};q.push(f);});var%20downVoteTimer=window.setTimeout(function(){q[0](1);},50);}());`

[Script #2](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/comments/2f13er/how_do_i_unsubscribe_from_all_subreddits/ck50u4t/):

> Try using this instead:
>
> `javascript:(function(){var%20q=[];$('.remove').each(function(){var%20that=this;var%20f=function(index){$(that).trigger('click');$(that).trigger('mousedown');setTimeout(function(){if(q[index]){q[index](index+1);}else{if(downVoteTimer){window.clearTimeout(upVoteTimer);}}},500);};q.push(f);});var%20downVoteTimer=window.setTimeout(function(){q[0](1);},50);}());`
>
> Chrome might auto remove the `javascript:` part so you need to manually re-add it

Comment: The "multireddit" link is HTTP ERROR 431.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand perfectly ur question.
Go to [this link](https://www.reddit.com/subreddits), and open the Developper tools and put this on the console

```
javascript:(function(){var q=[];$('.remove').each(function(){var that=this;var f=function(index){$(that).trigger('click');$(that).trigger('mousedown');setTimeout(function(){if(q[index]){q[index](index+1);}else{if(downVoteTimer){window.clearTimeout(upVoteTimer);}}},500);};q.push(f);});var downVoteTimer=window.setTimeout(function(){q[0](1);},50);}());
```

if it doesn't work, you can follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/4lun/898492d15722c9e10835), and try the other solutions

Comment: "open the console and put this on the console" - Can you please include screenshots and MUCH more detail? Are you referring to [Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) or Browser Console?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal this console :  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Outils/Console_JavaScript

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal: <kbd>F12</kbd>, the console tab, paste and execute.

Answer (score 0):

With Python and its API Wrapper for Reddit, called PRAW (Python Reddit API wrapper- https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can simply accomplish your goal.

```
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit('user', user_agent='Bulk Unsubscribe Script') #Getting credentials from praw.ini file.
for subreddit in reddit.user.subreddits(limit=None):
    subreddit.unsubscribe()
```

If you follow the earlier link to PRAW documentation, it will explain to you how to set up API access for your Reddit account (very easy- you can just do it through your preferences/settings panel in Reddit) and how to log into it.

Comment: 'Am I understanding correctly that you would like to bulk unsubscribe from all subreddits that you're currently subscribed to.' Yes. Please feel free to edit this. 'Are you familiar with Python and its API Wrapper for Reddit, called PRAW ' I'm unskilled at computers, and I'm not. Thanks though! I wish I change my whom to award that 50 bounty!